# "Wrong type argument" adding projects to treemacs

Tags: debugging, project, treemacs

I'm just setting up Treemacs for the first time. I am using Emacs' built in project management (not Projectile) and ideally want Treemacs to always show only the current project.

Currently, if I run `treemacs-add-and-display-current-project` or `treemacs-display-current-project-exclusively`, I get the error `Wrong type argument: stringp, (Git "PROJECTPATH"). What’s causing this?

Comment: Say `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` and do the command again, then paste the backtrace into your question.

Comment: Sounds like `treemacs` needs to fix the way it's using project.el. A bug report would help.